# What is the appropriate event type for Angular checkbox input events?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the correct type for the `event` parameter? I've attempted to use `InputEvent` and `HTMLInputElement`, but neither seems to work.

```
  changed(event) { //<---- event??
    console.log({ checked: event.target.checked });
  }
```

The full example:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>

    <input type="checkbox" (change)="changed($event)">
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  changed(event) { //<---- event??
    console.log({ checked: event.target.checked });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-trhxu8?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, when you're dealing with events, you typically use the `Event` type for the event parameter. However, if you want to access properties specific to the event target, such as `checked` for a checkbox, you would need to cast the event target to the appropriate type.

For your case, since you're listening to the `(change)` event of a checkbox, you can use `HTMLInputElement` for the event target. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>

    <input type="checkbox" (change)="changed($event)">
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  changed(event: Event) {
    const checkbox = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log({ checked: checkbox.checked });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

In this code:

`event: Event`: Specifies the type of the event parameter as `Event`.

`const checkbox = event.target as HTMLInputElement;`: Casts the event
target to `HTMLInputElement`, allowing you to access properties like
`checked`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy